# Can I use relative path with webpack dev server - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, reverse-proxy, react-scripts

When I run a development server on `localhost:3000` using `npm run start`, the server works as expected. I am using react-scripts, I have not ejected the react app.

What I am trying to do, is set up the dev server behind a reverse proxy. So `localhost:5572/author/name/` will point to the development server running on `localhost:3000`.

The setup is working fine, the index.html gets loaded. But as the dev server is running at `"/"`, the page tries to load scripts as `"<script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>"`. So, it expects the URL to be `localhost:5572/static/js/bundle.js`. But the reverse proxy is serving the same file at `localhost:5572/author/name/static/js/bundle.js`

Inside the package.json, I have specified

```
{
    ...
    "homepage": "./",
    ...
}
```

so my production builds have a relative path, but the dev builds don't.

Is there a way to have relative paths rather than absolute? Or is there a different solution I can use.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create file named `.env.development` in the root folder of your project. Add to the file the next string:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/author/name
```

This settings will affect only on dev mode. More details about how to define environment variables you can find [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env). And [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) is some information about using of public folder.